# Cannot override after_omniauth_failure_path_for in Devise

Tags: facebook, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, omniauth

I have my class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
and I'm overriding the after_omniauth_failure_path_for method:

```
protected
  def after_omniauth_failure_path_for resource
    '/report_failure'
  end
```

But the super one is the one that gets called.

I suspects that it's because the passthru workaround:

```
  devise_for :users do
    get '/users/auth/:provider'  => 'users/omniauth_callbacks#passthru'
  end
```

Does anybody knows how to overcome this issue?
I'm using Devise 2.0.4

This is the log file report:

```
Started GET "/users/auth/facebook/callback?error_reason=user_denied&error=access_denied&error_description=The+user+denied+your+request." for 77.124.184.115 at 2012-04-19 11:34:46 +0000
Processing by Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController#failure as HTML
  Parameters: {"error_reason"=>"user_denied", "error"=>"access_denied", "error_description"=>"The user denied your request."}
Redirected to http://myapp.com/users/sign_in
Completed 302 Found in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Edit: If I remove the passthru redirection, then it works:

```
#       def  devise_for :users do
#        get '/users/auth/:provider'  => 'users/omniauth_callbacks#passthru'
#      end
```

Thank you

Comment: Your error message is telling you that Devise isn't even using your `OmniauthCallbacksController`, it's using it's own.  I think @the8472 is right.  The code you posted does not show you setting `:omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks"`

Answer (score 1):

I had the `omniauth_callbacks` controller correctly set in my `routes.rb` but still could not override the `failure` or `after_omniauth_failure_path_for` method. The problem was that I had another devise user model setup with an empty path, before my problematic user model:

```rb
devise_for :customer_users, path: ''
# [...]
devise_for :users, module: 'users' # using a module instead of controllers
```

This led to always matching the `customer_user` mapping in [this](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/f5cc775a5feea51355036175994edbcb5e6af13c/lib/devise/omniauth.rb#L19) devise omniauth method. Hence, the failure was handle by the default `Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController`:

```
Processing by Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController#failure as HTML
```

The issue can be fixed by setting a not empty path for `customer_users`:

```
devise_for :customer_users, path: 'customer'
# or the default
devise_for :customer_users
```

I hope this helps in case someone makes the same mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add the `:controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks" }`
parameters to the devise_for route configuration, without it omniauth doesn't know which controller to redirect to after a failure.

Btw, passthru is not part of devise. You probably added it yourself?

Comment: I have this redirection in my routes.rb, and yes, I've added passthru myself according to many posts I've seen

Comment: I've tried this too, but it doesn't work, seems like you can't overwrite the omniauth_callbacks class like that.